# Having trouble defining a new type

Tags: haskell, mongodb

ok, so here's my current code:

```
import Database.MongoDB
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Data.UString

data Project = Project { name :: String , desc :: String
                       , category :: String , priority :: Int
                       , repeating :: Bool , done :: Bool } deriving (Show)

data Command m = Save ((DbAccess m) => (Collection -> Document -> m ()))

main = do
  pool <- newConnPool 1 $ host "127.0.0.1"
  (command:args) <- getArgs
  let add = Save $ save (u "projects") [(u "name") =: (u $ Prelude.concat args)]
--  let remove = delete (select [(u "name") =: (u $ Prelude.concat args)] (u "projects"))
  let update = Save $ save (u "projects") [(u "name") =: (u $ Prelude.concat args)]
  let commands = [("add", add),("update", update)]
  let (Just (Save action)) = Prelude.lookup command commands
  db <- access safe Master pool $ use (Database (u "test")) action
  print db
```

My basic problem is that the three possible outcomes for the user's command are either add, update, or remove (I'm messing around with MongoDB.)

Basic syntax for calling the script is ./script {add|update|remove} project name goes here

Add and update have the same return type, but remove has a different one, and since they have different type signatures, haskell's type checking isn't accepting it. I figured I'd have to make a new type to encapsulate both possibilities, as I kind of tried to do above, but I'm not getting anywhere. I'm also very new to haskell and programming in general, so excuse the messy code and possibly noobish question.

Comment: Could you wrap the different result types in an `Either` or so?

Comment: in this situation I could use Either, but I'd be limited to only using two different type sigs, so I wouldn't be able to extend functionality in the future.

Comment: I don't understand the question actually. All the commands already have same type, it is `commands :: DbAccess m => [(String, m ())]`. (Assuming you remove `Save` wrapper: `Command` datatype is invalid and useless here.)

Comment: if you have a working piece of code feel free to post it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you say that `remove` has different type. `save` and `delete` have different types, but after applying arguments they both return `DbAccess m => m ()`.

```
import Database.MongoDB
import System.Environment


commands :: DbAccess m => [String] -> [(String, m ())]
commands args = [("add", add),("update", update),("remove",remove)]
  where
    uargs = u $ Prelude.concat args
    add    = save (u "projects") [u "name" =: uargs]
    update = save (u "projects") [u "name" =: uargs]
    remove = delete $ select [u "name" =: uargs] (u "projects")


main = do
  pool <- newConnPool 1 $ host "127.0.0.1"
  (command:args) <- getArgs
  let (Just action) = Prelude.lookup command $ commands args
  db <- access safe Master pool $ use (Database (u "test")) action
  print db
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could have `data Command2` with two constructs, say `Save1` and `Save2`. The first encapsulates add/update and the other remove.

Some changes you then need to apply is something like this:

```
let commands = [("add", Save1 add),("update", Save1 update), ("remove", Save2 remove)]
```

And instead of `use` you can maybe define something like this:

```
use2 db (Save1 action)  = use db action
use2 db (Save2 action)  = use db action
```

For everything to work you would also need to change the lookup to this.

```
let (Just action) = Prelude.lookup command commands
```

Note that I removed `Save` pattern matcher now.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: my edited code: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/342686/ || and its errors: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/342685/

Comment: The first errors is probably because you use `save` in the wrong way. Thats a separate matter.

As for the latter 2 erorrs on line 18 and 20, that is because your strange data defnition for Command. If you just compile without implementing `remove` (which is a good idea), you should probably use your old data definition. `data Command = Save` Isn't so useful as the constructor `Save` don't take any arguments.

Comment: ok so I got it to a working state (http://paste.pocoo.org/show/342716/), however I proceeded to try and add a query function, but my new type doesn't work for it. both add and remove had the same output, just different inputs, however query has a different output as well, as seen in the error: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/342717/

Comment: If add and remove have different inputs, it doesn't matter if they have the same output for the type checker. Your `data` Should look like this: `data Command = Save <signatue of add/update here> | Rem <signature of remove here> | Que ...`

Comment: Also, `use'` is indeed a better name than `use2` :)

Comment: I tried to define Command like that in my original question, but it kept throwing errors. This is how I see it: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/342729/ - which is pulled directly from the API page, and here are the errors: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/342731/

Comment: Just remove the DbAccess restriction. In general you're **discouraged** from having type class restrictions in data definitions.

Comment: already tried that(http://paste.pocoo.org/show/342925/), still get tons of errors - http://paste.pocoo.org/show/342924/